# how to handle refcursor not retrieving data in PGSQL

Tags: postgresql, ref-cursor

How to handle refcursor not retrieving data(empty resultset) in PGSQL?

```
create or replace function function_1( In tblname varchar(15))
 returns refcursor
 language plpgsql
 as $$
    declare
    v_cnt integer;
    r_ref refcursor='ref2';
    v_sql text='select * from tbl where 1=2';--default statement;shld return empty if 
                                              --input is invalid
begin

    if tblname ilike 'scientist' then
         v_sql:='select * from tbl'; --table name 1
   end if;
   
open r_ref for
     execute v_sql;
 return r_ref;  


end;
$$;
```

Is there any other way to handle without using dynamic sql?
execution: Test case 1 : should return empty result set

```
select * from function_1('invalid');  
fetch all in "ref2";
```

execution: Test case 2 : should return proper data from able

```
select * from function_1('scientist');  
fetch all in "ref2";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a dynamic query when you only have one test case to cover = 'scientist'. In this case, you can simply do :

```
create or replace function function_1( In tblname varchar(15))
 returns setof scientist language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if tblname ilike 'scientist' then
         return query
           select * from scientist ;
   end if;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: an empty refcursor needs to be populated if an invalid tblname is given.This is the requirement of the Application.

Comment: What does *"empty refcursor"* stand for : no row returned ? one row returned with the sql `NULL` value ? ... ?